# Alternative for Celery salt and Coconut flour

Tags: salt, flour, shrimp, celery

I'm trying to make this recipe:
http://www.platedwithstyle.com/2015/03/01/cajun-garlic-butter-shrimp/

I know i can find "substitues" for celery salt and coconut flour online 
but I want to know if i can use regular salt and all purpose flour for this specific recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "celery" component of the salt is just there for flavor, and shouldn't affect how the dish cooks. Celery has a deeply vegetal flavor that can enhance others in the dish (hence why you see it in many soups, stews, and braises) but there's enough else in this preparation that you probably won't miss it much.

I wouldn't try to use regular flour, though. The coconut flour is being added here at the last minute to thicken the dish; regular flour will do this too, but unless it's cooked for several minutes it will retain a grainy, bready flavor. You might want to try a different common substitute like cornstarch, which thickens quickly and has a neutral flavor (it's also used in many American Chinese recipes). Whatever you do, be sure to follow the advice in the recipe and add it in very slow sprinklings, stirring in between so that it doesn't clump.

Comment: In (american) chinese recipes cornstarch, rice starch .. for thickening would usually be mixed with a cold liquid before adding, as would be advisable here too. But if you look at the photos, it seems to be more of a finer type of grated coconut than literal flour used (also compare pictures of "coconut flour" - also more grated-like).  I would take some fresh or frozen grated coconut and mince it fine with a knife or mezzaluna... dried or dried/soaked could work too but would possibly  get too tough/sawdust-like.

Comment: Yes, it says the coconut flour is for texture, so grated coconut would work well, but NOT the sweetened kind! ;-) As a New Orleans native (altho I moved away as a teen), I can tell you that coconut is not common to Cajun cooking so from a flavor perspective I would say you could very well leave the coconut flour out entirely. If you want some additional texture, you could tossing it with seasoned bread crumbs at the end. If you want thicker sauce, add a cornstarch slurry as @rackandboneman suggests.

Comment: The sweetness can probably be rebalanced by using less sugar during seasoning, but most baking-aisle grated coconut products i have had are very tough and gritty affairs....